# On a view source, what language is this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

So I tagged this as HTML, CSS and JS because it is on the front side.  I can see the if statements so it appears to be more than just markup.  I read it as follows - if less than IE7 load classes ie and ie6, if ie7 load ie and ie7, if ie8 load ie8 and finally if ie9 or greater or not ie than do nothing

Where is the documentation for this "language"

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]><!-->
```

Comment: [Conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are deprecated since IE10.

Comment: Please [try googling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @cadegalt Reading the linked article: "`As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode`".

Answer (score 3):

These are called conditional comments, and are not a language per se. Unless you call IE a language.

They are nothing more than fancy HTML comments in a format that Microsoft decided they would allow for special instructions to IE

Read more here : http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Comment: quirksmode articles are the best.

Answer (score 1):

These are [IE conditional comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

They are called as `conditional IE classes`

Read more about them, [here](http://peterwilson.cc/html-ie-classes/) and [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/).

Comment: I agree, that there is no need to support IE7 or less any more.